# Ruta con parámetro en app.routes.ts no funciona

Tags: angular

En mi archivo **app.routes.ts** tengo estas definiciones:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'star-ships', component: StarShipsComponent },
    { path: 'starship/:id', component: StarshipComponent },
    { path: '**', pathMatch:'full', redirectTo: 'star-ships' }
];
```

La ruta ***'starship/:id'*** no funciona ni llamada desde el navegador ni desde una función del componente con **.navigate**

Si le quito el parámetro ***'/:id'*** ya se puede llamar desde navegador y **.navigate**:

```
{ path: 'starship', component: StarshipComponent },
```

No consigo ver el problema y necesito pasar el parámetro, ¿alguna idea por favor?

Muchas gracias

Comment: La ruta `'starship/:id'` espera un parámetro si no se lo pasas no encuentra ninguna coincidencia y no renderiza ningún componente. Si quieres navegar a dicho componente tienes que pasar un `id` o cualquier cosa que espera ese componente desde la ruta. Por ejemplo, `'starship/1234'` esta ruta si que concuerda con la que espera angular.

Comment: Efectivamente 'starship/1234' funciona si defino el parámetro '/:id' en la ruta.
En cambio no funciona si utilizo .navigate( ['/starship', sh] ).
Si no uso el parámetro '/:id', el .navigate si funciona.
Lo importante es el .navigate, así se queda funcionando.
Muchas gracias

Comment: intentebta removiendo esta linea { path: '**', pathMatch:'full', redirectTo: 'star-ships' }

Answer (score 0):

la función que estas usando es `this.router.navigate(['algo'])` verdad?

Si es asi, la id no se la debes pasar con una ",", debe ser con un símbolo "+" para que quede concatenado, algo asi como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
navigateStarship(starship_id:string){
    this.router.navigate(['/starship' + starship_id]);
}
```

Comment: La información aportada por hawks fué suficiente para poder hacer funcionar el .navigate. Esta me permitió comprender cómo funciona y decidir la mejor opción. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola compañero para poder acceder a la ruta con un parámetro utilizando la etiqueta `<a></a>`, debes utilizar el siguiente código

```
<a [routerLink]="['/tu-ruta-del-path/', elValorDelParámetro">
el icono</a>
```

y para utilizar el navigate sería así

```
this.router.navigate(['tu-ruta-del-path',elValorDelParámetro])
```

espero que te ayude amigo

Comment: no olvides importar el router de angular y colocarlo en el constructor

Comment: En su día, `this.router.navigate(['/heroe', idx]);` me funionó con la ruta `{ path: 'heroe/:id', component: HeroeComponent },`.
Poco después, lo expuesto en el mensaje de cabecera no y tuve que quitar el '/:id' del path para que funcionara.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola mira solo asi te quitas de broncas xd jeje saludos devs

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. No uses imágenes salvo que sea explícitamente necesario, ya que no todos pueden verlas, 2. en ningún momento explicaste qué aparece en la imagen. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta, o elimínala directamente.